# Can't find UEFI boot option in BIOS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, uefi

I am using an old machine which has Intel i5-2410M processor 2nd generation.

I am planning to do clean installation of Windows 10 in UEFI as recommended by Microsoft on a recently purchased SSD. I have already created a bootable Windows 10 USB using Rufus with target system as UEFI, however, I am not sure if this bootable usb will work with my machine as I am not able to find UEFI in BIOS. I also intend to install Ubuntu in a separate partition.

Can anyone help me how to set firmware settings as UEFI before proceeding with this installation?

This is the detail of the motherboard:

[Computer Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPRLW.png)

Comment: UEFI replaces BIOS. You have either UEFI or BIOS. You cannot find UEFI in BIOS, like you cannot find an automobile in a horse-drawn carriage.

Comment: Right now I have downloaded the ISO image file for Win 10. I am using Rufus to create the bootable USB. Is it possible that I can create it using UEFI as target system and install it in my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suspect that the PC you are trying to boot is not UEFI based but BIOS based (these are the two options, it's either one or the other), then you should make sure that the *Target system* option in Rufus says "BIOS (or UEFI-CSM)" (Note: UEFI-CSM is just "BIOS emulation" from UEFI, but you don't need to care about this unless your system is UEFI based, which doesn't appear to be your case).

Note that you may have to change the *Partition scheme* option of Rufus to "MBR" before you can set *Target system* to "BIOS".

That's all there is to it really: You just need to make sure that *Target system* in Rufus does match the type of computer you are trying to boot.

You may also want to look at [this entry from the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_created_a_Windows_installation_drive_but_it_doesnt_boot).

Comment: Thank you very much Akeo! I thought I could update my motherboard firmware setting to UEFI (lately I realized that it's not available from the manufacturer!). And your solution did help. Since I am not going for more than 4 partitions and higher capacity hard disk, I think I could still survive with the BIOS for a while more. :-)